# Declare statement is not supported in SQL command of SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying do the following using SSIS. I am using SDT latest version and querying SQL Server 2008 R2.

Could somebody suggest if I am doing it wrong and if there is a better way in doing it

I basically need to execute a stored procedures from the source and store the results it in the destination. There are around 20 stored procedures.

Each of the stored procedures takes XML as input. I have created a Control task within that a data flow task. Within the data flow i am creating the oledb source.

I have selected Data access mode as SQL command. I am created my query below but when i preview , I get error saying that declare statement is not supported

```
DECLARE @xmldata XML

SET @xmldata = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 (mc.companyId) AS id
                FROM ciqMarketCap mc 
                JOIN ciqCompany c ON c.companyid = mc.companyid
                WHERE c.companyStatusTypeId NOT IN (5, 6) 
                  AND c.companyTypeId IN (1, 4) 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('partyIds'))

EXEC getPartiesMarketData @xmldata
```

How do I execute the rest of the stored procedures? Do I need to create several oledb sources?

Comment: why not create a wrapper SP which does what you need, and call that from SSIS?

Comment: Do you mean I execute the 20 storedprocs within the wrapper but how would i direct 20 resultsets to the 20 tables in the destination

Comment: I am new SSIS. It would be helpful if you give me an example. Also please note that the logic for the xml is the same for all SPs

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing in steps:

Create variables in SSIS:

xmldata string set = ""

SQLquery string set formula of "Exec getPartiesMarketData " + @xmldata

In execute sql task enter sql statement into Direct Input:

SELECT DISTINCT top 1000 (mc.companyId) as id
FROM ciqMarketCap mc 
JOIN ciqCompany c 
       ON c.companyid = mc.companyid
WHERE c.companyStatusTypeId NOT IN (5,6) AND  c.companyTypeId IN (1,4) for xml path(''), type, root('partyIds')

Change the result set to XML

Map result xmldata

Then in another execute sql connected you will do your real query:

SQL Source type: variable

Source Variable: SQLquery

I haven't tested this, but I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: What about using data flow task , oledb source , connection manager. How do I configure these

Comment: what does the sp actually do? If it is a cursor, you mind as well do a foreach loop in SSIS and skip the XML.

Comment: The storedprocedure contains joins that would retrieve records based on xml input provided. Not using cursor

Comment: How about creating the XML above as a view and just refencing the view in your stored procedure?

Comment: So what I understand from your suggestion is that create view that will contain the query for generating xml. Create several sql tasks that will execute the stored procedures and reference the view. Am I right. What query do I right in the connection manager

Comment: There is one update. There is no more xml input required for the storeprocedures. What I need to do is execute 20 storedprocedures either sequentially or asynchronously. So currently I have created a Dataflow task. Under Dataflowtask I have created source oledb source. My question here is how do I write the extract data logic. As I told you I have 20 storedprocedures. Do I create 20 oledb sources

Comment: no. just 1 oledb connection, a foreach and a loop. I'll show you in another answer.

Comment: It should not only execute the storedprocedures but with every execution of storedprocedures it should insert the resultset into a table defined in the database. So I probably need to store the resultset of each storedprocedure  in a variable and loop probably loop that variable to insert the records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149016/discussion-between-tom-and-keithl).

Comment: Are the structure of the SPs returned the same thing? Does the results go to the same table? Your answer is data flow now. You keep changing the problem you have.

Comment: I have created tables in the destination database that contains columns that match the resultset of the storeproc

Comment: All i want to do is execute these storeprocedures , fetch the result set and stored the values in the destination tables

Comment: Just do 20 data flows that write the result set to DB. I have to get back to work.

Comment: why 20 dataflows cant i not use foreach container

Comment: You said tables indicating that the data flow is different where as the destination is different. Just do it for one SP first and then see what you can do for all of them.